# Выборка количества записей из таблицы

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Всем привет.

Я продолжаю изучать sql. На сей раз новая задача:
Есть таблица. В ней два столбца: собственно сам `id` записи, и еще один столбец `user_id` который хранит Id пользователя, который совершил это действие. Вопрос такой: модно ли без участия сервера (в моем случае PHP) сделать выборку, чтобы в итоге запрос выдал количество записей, принадлежащих этому пользователю. То есть выдать, сколько записей (выполненных действий) есть у каждого пользователя:
`User 1 - 10 
User 2 - 7  
User 5 - 5  
User 3 - 2  
User 4 - 1`

Comment: Какую странную таблицу Вы создали!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(`user_id`) AS total FROM `table` GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Я не перестаю удивляться на возможности SQL

Comment: @mountpoint а как изменить запрос, если мне надо подсчитывать только те записи, при которых есть определенный параметр? Например, у каких-то записей поле `action` стоит 1, а где-то 0, а мне надо, только где 1, то как быть?

Comment: @mountpoint а, все, сам разобрался, добавил `where action = 1` :D